# Isometric Tables in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices

Can someone please help me with a simple LaTeX code to draw something like the attached picture?
[image: 3D Matrix table]

Comment: Is the misalignment of the face containing "Item_1", "Item_2" intentional and should be reproduced?

Comment: No, it's not intentional, I'd be glad if the shape is more regular. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

A possible solution based on http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku-3d-cube/ :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{colortop}{RGB}{184,223,155}
\definecolor{colorside}{RGB}{0,209,54}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Att}{Att}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Item}{Item}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,font=\scriptsize},on grid]
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=-0.5,rotate=90},yslant=-0.5]
  \shade[right color=colorside!30, left color=colorside!50] (-1,0) rectangle +(4,3);
  \node at (-0.5,2.25) {};
  \node at (0.5,2.25) {$\Att_1$};
  \node at (1.5,2.25) {$\Att_2$};
  \node at (2.5,2.25) {$\Att_3$};
  \node at (-0.5,0.75) {User};
  \node at (0.5,0.75) {$1$};
  \node at (1.5,0.75) {$0$};
  \node at (2.5,0.75) {$0$};
  \draw (-1,0) grid[ystep=1.5] (3,3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5},yslant=0.5]
  \shade[right color=colorside!70,left color=colorside!10] (3,-3) rectangle +(5,3);
  \node at (3.5,-0.5) {};
  \node at (4.5,-0.5) {$\Att_1$};
  \node at (5.5,-0.5) {$\Att_2$};
  \node at (6.5,-0.5) {$\Att_3$};
  \node at (7.5,-0.5) {$\Att_4$};
  \node at (3.5,-1.5) {$\Item_1$};
  \node at (4.5,-1.5) {$0$};
  \node at (5.5,-1.5) {$1$};
  \node at (6.5,-1.5) {$1$};
  \node at (7.5,-1.5) {$1$};
  \node at (3.5,-2.5) {$\Item_2$};
  \node at (4.5,-2.5) {$0$};
  \node at (5.5,-2.5) {$0$};
  \node at (6.5,-2.5) {$1$};
  \node at (7.5,-2.5) {$0$};
  \draw (3,-3) grid (8,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
  ]
  \shade[bottom color=colortop!10, top color=colortop!80] (8,4) rectangle +(-5,-4);
  \node[font=\scriptsize\color{red},rotate=-90] at (5.5,2) {User--item feature matrix};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>I edited this answer with the owner's agreement.</sub>

Comment: I was doing kind of the same, so no point in giving a really similar answer, but I'll leave [`in pastebin`](http://pastebin.com/g4Vwrn8g) my code, in case you want to incorporate some of the modifications I made for my answer.

Comment: I can't access to `pastebin.com` from here. Please upload to another site if possible.

Comment: Any site you know? The only one I've used for pasting code is `patebin`.

Comment: Do you use the chat room? I could leave it there.

Comment: I created a chat room [`here`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14505/discussion-between-ferahfeza-and-gonzalo-medina) and left the code there; see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15512343#15512343

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thank you for your effort and congratulation for 200k rep.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [`pst-3dplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot,xcolor,multido,graphicx}

\newcommand{\clap}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{\footnotesize #1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
  % Draw box shape + colour
  \psset{linewidth = 0.5pt, linecolor = black!30, fillstyle = solid, unit = 1.2, Alpha = 50, Beta = 30}
  \pstThreeDSquare[plane = xy, fillcolor = green!65!white](0,0,3)(5,0,0)(0,5,0)
  \pstThreeDSquare[plane = xz, fillcolor = red!65!white](0,5,0)(5,0,0)(0,0,3)
  \pstThreeDSquare[plane = yz, fillcolor = blue!65!white](5,0,0)(0,5,0)(0,0,3)

  % Draw on box shape
  \pstThreeDLine(5,0,1.5)(5,5,1.5)
  \multido{\rY=1.25+1.25}{3}{\pstThreeDLine(5,\rY,0)(5,\rY,3)}
  \multido{\iZ=1+1}{2}{\pstThreeDLine(5,5,\iZ)(0,5,\iZ)}
  \multido{\iX=1+1}{4}{\pstThreeDLine(\iX,5,0)(\iX,5,3)}

  % Annotate the faces
  \psset{planecorr = normal, plane = yz, pOrigin = c}
  \pstPlanePut(5,0.625,0.75){\clap{\texttt{User}}}
  \pstPlanePut(5,1.875,0.75){\clap{0}}\pstPlanePut(5,1.875,2.25){\clap{\texttt{Att\_1}}}
  \pstPlanePut(5,3.125,0.75){\clap{1}}\pstPlanePut(5,3.125,2.25){\clap{\texttt{Att\_2}}}
  \pstPlanePut(5,4.375,0.75){\clap{1}}\pstPlanePut(5,4.375,2.25){\clap{\texttt{Att\_3}}}

  \psset{plane = xz}
  \pstPlanePut(4.5,5,0.5){\clap{\texttt{Item\_2}}}
    \pstPlanePut(3.5,5,0.5){\clap{0}}
    \pstPlanePut(2.5,5,0.5){\clap{0}}
    \pstPlanePut(1.5,5,0.5){\clap{1}}
    \pstPlanePut(0.5,5,0.5){\clap{1}}
  \pstPlanePut(4.5,5,1.5){\clap{\texttt{Item\_1}}}
    \pstPlanePut(3.5,5,1.5){\clap{0}}
    \pstPlanePut(2.5,5,1.5){\clap{1}}
    \pstPlanePut(1.5,5,1.5){\clap{1}}
    \pstPlanePut(0.5,5,1.5){\clap{0}}
  %   
    \pstPlanePut(3.5,5,2.5){\clap{\texttt{Att\_1}}}
    \pstPlanePut(2.5,5,2.5){\clap{\texttt{Att\_2}}}
    \pstPlanePut(1.5,5,2.5){\clap{\texttt{Att\_3}}}
    \pstPlanePut(0.5,5,2.5){\clap{\texttt{Att\_4}}}

  \psset{plane = xy}
  \pstPlanePut(2.5,2.5,3){\clap{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{\normalsize User-item feature matrix}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```