# Is there any way to write documents in Aurebesh characters?

Tags: fonts

The question says it all, basically.
Is there any way to write in Aurebesh characters, the writing system for Galaxy Basic (Star Wars fictional language)?
Does such font exist, or is there a specific package for this?

Comment: Could this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301897/star-wars-text-effect be useful?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm searching, I'm talking about using the Aurebesh characters as a final output for the document, this alphabet: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh/Legends

Comment: There are already ways to use this alphabet in MS Word, but I'd prefer writing in \LaTeX

Comment: You can use any font you like with `xelatex`/`lualatex` and the `fontspec` package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1478/87678

Comment: Thanks David, if you can post this as an answer I will mark yours as useful

Comment: @Birrabenzina -- please add the url for the alphabet to the text of the question.  comments are easy to ignore, and apparently all but impossible to search.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem, I simply installed the ttf font and compiled using XeLaTeX with the fontspec package, it worked really well