# Outlines for a TeX label in MetaPost

Tags: metapost

Is there a way to get outlines for a TeX label in MetaPost, containing something reasonably complex, say: `$\sum_{x=0}^{10}x^2$`? I know that I can get outlines for separate glyphs using `glyph`, but how to preserve a layout?

Comment: Are you using "pure" MetaPost or are variants allowed? ConTeXt has some outlining functions, but I'm not sure this answers your question.

Comment: In general I'm interested in a solution which would work with standalone MetaPost, but a ConTeXt solution would help too.

Comment: To be precise, I believe I know how to do it in ConTeXt, but it doesn't work in standalone MP.

Comment: Another way is going wild: `pdflatex` > `pdf2ps` > `pstoedit`  or `latex` > `dvips` > `pstoedit` to get a MetaPost file, perhaps?

Comment: This would work for one-off tasks, for sure, but it would be quite inconvenient to do it from within MetaPost on larger scale.

Comment: You need Lua to get access to the outlines, so you'll need to use either ConTeXt or LuaTeX+mplib.

Comment: @HenriMenke This could be a soultion, but then I'd need to be able to transfer the outlines to standalone MP. Hence this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580214/convert-a-path-to-string-save-path-to-a-file-in-metapost
Or maybe there's another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `for e within p` does, where `p` is a picture variable.  Consider this small example:

```
input TEX
picture p; p = TEX("$\sum_{x=0}^{10}x^2$");
for e within p:
    if textual e:
        message "(" & decimal xpart e & "," & decimal ypart e & ") " 
                    & fontpart e & " " & textpart e;
    elseif stroked e:
        show pathpart e;
    fi
endfor
end
```

if you run this through plain `mpost` you should get this output:

```
(0,7.472) cmex10 P
(10.5162,5.0091) cmr7 10
(10.5162,-2.9888) cmmi7 x
(15.0339,-2.9888) cmr7 =0
(27.2797,0) cmmi10 x
(32.9736,3.6154) cmr7 2
```

which tells you the position, the font used, and the ASCII character used in that font.  (Note that the sum symbol is "P" in `cmex10`).   And from this you can use `glyph` to get the outlines for each character in the `textpart` string.

From my experiments, this only works with plain `mpost`.  I do not get the same output from `lualatex` + `luamplib` -- I guess because the font management is so different.

### Slightly more complete example

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
input TEX
beginfig(1)
picture p; p = TEX("$\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{10}x^2$");
for e within p:
    if textual e:
        pair o; o = (xpart e, ypart e) scaled 100/8; 
        for i=1 upto length textpart e:
            string s; s = substring (i-1, i) of textpart e;
            picture g; g = glyph ASCII s of fontpart e scaled 1/8;
            picture out; out = image(
            for ee within g:
                draw pathpart ee;
            endfor);
            draw out shifted o;
            o := o + (xpart lrcorner out, 0);
        endfor
    fi
endfor
endfig;
end
```

but I am not sure I have quite understood the spacing and scaling information. The documentation is a bit sparse...

[image]

### Compatibility with `luamplib`

Note that (at present) the ideas shown here only work with plain Metapost.  The built-in `TEX()` macro that is provided by `luamplib` (for use with `lualatex`) returns a picture with just one "part" and that part has no "textual" elements in it, and the only "stroked" part is the bounding box of the typeset text.