# Formatting the sum of two hypermatrices with tikz

Tags: matrices, tikz-cd

I have written the sum of two hypermatrices with tikz with the following code.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd} 
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

  \begin{document}

 \begin{equation*}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.2cm,minimum height=1.2cm}]
 \matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
 {
 b_1^1 b^2_1  b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^1  b^2_1  b^3_2  \\
 b_1^1 b^2_2  b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^1  b^2_2  b^3_2  \\
 };
 \matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(4.5 cm,3cm)$)
 {
 b_1^2 b^2_1 b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^2 b^2_1 b^3_2  \\
 b_1^2 b^2_2 b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^2 b^2_2 b^3_2  \\
 };
\draw[dashed](mA.south west)--(mB.south west);
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\ \   +   \ \ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.2cm,minimum height=1.2cm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
c_1^1 c^2_1  c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^1  c^2_1  c^3_2  \\
c_1^1 c^2_2  c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^1  c^2_2  c^3_2  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(4.5 cm,3cm)$)
{
c_1^2 c^2_1 c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^2 c^2_1 c^3_2  \\
c_1^2 c^2_2 c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^2 c^2_2 c^3_2  \\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.south west)--(mB.south west);
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

I am struggling to lift the addition sign up to the center of the hypermatrices. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The following formatting approach for such matrices may be of passing interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192620/plot-3d-stacked-squares-with-shadow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\vcenter` to vertically center the pictures (matrices) in the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.2cm,minimum height=1.2cm}]
 \matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
 {
 b_1^1 b^2_1  b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^1  b^2_1  b^3_2  \\
 b_1^1 b^2_2  b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^1  b^2_2  b^3_2  \\
 };
 \matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(4.5 cm,3cm)$)
 {
 b_1^2 b^2_1 b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^2 b^2_1 b^3_2  \\
 b_1^2 b^2_2 b^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} b_1^2 b^2_2 b^3_2  \\
 };
\draw[dashed](mA.south west)--(mB.south west);
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\ \   +   \ \ 
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=1.2cm,minimum height=1.2cm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
c_1^1 c^2_1  c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^1  c^2_1  c^3_2  \\
c_1^1 c^2_2  c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^1  c^2_2  c^3_2  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(4.5 cm,3cm)$)
{
c_1^2 c^2_1 c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^2 c^2_1 c^3_2  \\
c_1^2 c^2_2 c^3_1 & \hspace{1mm} c_1^2 c^2_2 c^3_2  \\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.south west)--(mB.south west);
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could put everything in one `tikzpicture`.